# How to translate grails 2 LDAP Active Directory values to work with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, grails, active-directory, ldap

I'm having problems connecting to LDAP Active Directory using Spring Boot. I've been using values found in our Grails 2 app but must be missing something.

**Grails 2 Values example**

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveDatabaseRoles = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = 'manager@domain.local'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = 'password'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = 'ldap://domain.local:389'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.ignorePartialResultException = true 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = 'ou=users,dc=domain,dc=local'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter = "sAMAccountName={0}"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.searchSubtree = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.auth.hideUserNotFoundExceptions = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.attributesToReturn = ['mail', 'displayName']
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ['customAuthenticationProvider','ldapAuthProvider']
```

Here is one of the many variations that I've tried in Spring Boot. I'm pretty positive it's not searching the manager / password correctly.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .contextSource().url("ldap://domain.local:389")
            .managerDn("uid=manager@domain.local,ou=users")
            .managerPassword("password")
            .and()
            .userSearchBase("ou=users,dc=domain,dc=local")
            .userDnPatterns("sAMAccountName={0}");

    }
}
```

build.gradle ldap dependencies

```
compile("org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core")
compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap")
compile("com.unboundid:unboundid-ldapsdk")
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by setting it up like this:

```
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource().url("ldap://domain.local:389/ou=users,dc=domain,dc=local")
                .managerDn("manager@domain.local").managerPassword("password")
                .and()
                .userSearchFilter("sAMAccountName={0}");
```